# Equation of plane that goes for intersection of 2 planes and is perpindicular to another plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, cross-product

Really don't know what to do here, went to a tutor neither did he.

Okay first the problem:

Find the equation of the plane that passes through the line of intersection of the planes
x − z = 2 and y + 3z = 1
and is perpendicular to the plane
x + y − 4z = 3

What I have done, not sure if it's right I only have one chance to get it right so I'd really appreciate any input please

< 1, 0, -1 > X < 0, 1, 3 >

which creates the vector: < 1, -3, 1 >

now I crossed it with the normal vector of the third plane:

< 1 , -3 , 1 > X < 1 , 1 , 4>

which creates the vector: < 11, 5 , 4 >

From there I said that if I took a point on the line of intersection and dot product-ed it with the above vector (which is parallel with the plane) then I'd get the equation of the plane.

So I took the two equations and created: 3x + y - 7 = 0

I made the point (1, 4, 0)

So now,

< 11, 5, 4 > dot

which makes 11x + 5y + 4z - 31 = 0

---

Thanks for reading if you have, any advice goes a long way, will reply asap

Comment: As the others have commented, $(1,4,0)$ is not on the intersection line. It isn't even on the planes you are intersecting, e.g. $1-0\ne2$. You need to find the three coordinates $x,y,z$ that satisfy both $x-z=2$ and $y+3z=1$. For instance, take $z=0$ and then use the equations to find $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct normal, incorrect point
The point should be a point on the line of intersection, so if you take $z=0$ then $x=2,y=1$

Comment: wouldn't either point be suitable?

Comment: the point should lie on the plane, what we know of those points of the plane are the points of the line of intersection, so we have to get one of them. Your point does not lie on this line

Comment: Wait so am I right in thinking that I can simply combine the two plane equations to find the equation of the line? 3x + y - 7 = 0

Comment: not combine, but solve them i.e. find a point that satisfies both equation

Comment: Yeah, so how does the point (1, 4, 0) not satisfy the equation 3x + y -7 = 0 ??? Is that equation wrong by your estimation?

Comment: this equation does not make sense, you have to consider only the original equation **not** their combination

Comment: I see, you're right, good point, I'll redo some calculations! Thanks!

Comment: One more thing to solve two equations in 3 unknowns you can take any value for one of the unknowns and calculate the others as i did above, Glad to help out

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really neat way of doing problems involving the line of intersection of two planes.  Consider the equation
$$a(x-z-2)+b(y+3z-1)=0\ ,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.  This is the equation of a plane, because it has the right form, namely
$$({\rm constant})x+({\rm constant})y+({\rm constant})z+({\rm constant})=0\ .$$
Also, if $(x,y,z)$ is on the line of intersection of your first two planes, then $x-z=2$ and $y+3z=1$, so this equation is satisfied.  In other words, this is the equation of a plane which contains the line of intersection, and you need to choose $a$ and $b$ in such a way that your third condition is also satisfied.

The normal to this plane is $(a,b,-a+3b)$, and you want this to be perpendicular to $(1,1,-4)$.  Using the dot product gives $5a-11b=0$, and you can take for example $a=11$, $b=5$.  Substitute back into the equation at the top of this answer to get
$$11x+5y+4z-27=0\ .$$

Comment: Okay I'm confused because I don't understand why you can add two planes together (with a scalar) and have it be the equation of a plane which intersects both. edit: I guess im wondering if you could give me a brief theoretical explanation? Sorry and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jacoo, I'm not adding planes, I'm adding equations.  For the rest, see expanded answer.

Comment: Oh, I understand now,  thank you.